# How to handle Firefox Upload File window with Selenium WebDriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-firefoxdriver

I know this topic is a duplicate but , I have applied other solutions too , and as an outcome I have a problem about sending the correct key to correct place for File Upload window.

I have used this piece of code to Open and send keys to Upload File:

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("upload-resume-button"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/Users/EvrenosCareer/Desktop/filename.pdf");
```

By sending keys correct button gets activated and File Upload window opens as expected , but keys was send as something else , and it appears down left corner of the browser; not File upload window. Please check this link , 5 sec video to see exactly what I am talking about: https://evrenos-hotmail.tinytake.com/sf/MTcxNDY0N181Njg2OTY1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly do **fileInput.sendKeys("C:/Users/EvrenosCareer/Desktop/filename.pdf")** if the type of the element is "file" else you will have to upload file using **Robot** class. You don't have to click on **fileInput** to send keys on that element.

**Upload file through Robot class:**

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("upload-resume-button"));
 element.click();
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("path to File");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: That is the button , we are talking about , I am trying to send key through it, when you click or try to send keys FileUpload window of Firefox opens. '<button class="button button--theme" onclick="$('#resume-input').click(); return false;" id="upload-resume-button">
                Upload Your Resume
            </button>'

Comment: You can't send keys on this button. Use Robot class for uploading the file.

Comment: Updated the answer with the function for uploading the file using Robot Class.

Comment: for example My file , is on desktop , and path is this: C:\Users\Evrenos-SuperCareer\Desktop\file.pdf   , How should I write the path to the "path_to_file" for string selection? (I am sorry , I am new on this things and probably it is a stupid question)

Comment: You can try manually on the opened window by giving this path. If it gets accepted and the file is uploaded, it will be accepted by selenium as well

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you @Monika